# Retrofit Android API Get without nested array

Tags: android, json, kotlin, retrofit

This is my first android project (I'm a php developer) but i'm struggling to see how to take this example which uses a nested structure under `data` for the json array whereas my data is not double nested like this example.

The excample code I am trying to modify is from here https://github.com/datanapps/RetrofitKotlin and the key differences in the json are todo with the nesting.

Original

```
{
  "page": 1,
  "per_page": 6,
  "total": 12,
  "total_pages": 2,
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "email": "george.bluth@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "George",
      "last_name": "Bluth",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "email": "james.smith@reqres.in",
      "first_name": "James",
      "last_name": "Smith",
      "avatar": "https://reqres.in/img/faces/1-image.jpg"
    }
  ]
}
```

whereas mine is simply

```
[
  {
    "_id": "62f4cb4e131d9d00046a1b9c",
    "device": "AndroidAPS-DexcomG6",
    "date": 1660209967000,
    "dateString": "2022-08-11T09:26:07.000Z",
    "isValid": true,
    "sgv": 133,
    "direction": "Flat",
    "type": "sgv",
    "created_at": "2022-08-11T09:26:38.326Z",
    "mills": 1660209998326
  },
  {
    "_id": "62f4cb4e131d9d00046a1b9c",
    "device": "AndroidAPS-DexcomG6",
    "date": 1660209967000,
    "dateString": "2022-08-11T09:26:07.000Z",
    "isValid": true,
    "sgv": 133,
    "direction": "Flat",
    "type": "sgv",
    "created_at": "2022-08-11T09:26:38.326Z",
    "mills": 1660209998326
  }
]
```

Specifically I want to query the SGV values, direction and date

Thanks

Comment: Read about Json serialization libraries: Gson/Moshi etc. One of best chains for api handle is Retrofit2+OkHttp3+Coroutines+Gson. Medium may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You "return type" of "method" in Retrofit "interface" will be:

```
List<MyModel>
```

And MyModel:

```
data class MyModel(val _id:String, val device:String,...)
```

Comment: thanks for the quick response, looking through this code that doesn't seem to fit with the example too well. Perhaps I'm using a bad example to start with that is over complicated ?